# Optional casting to a variable whose Type is a class type in Swift

Tags: swift, types, casting, sprite-kit

I've looked for similar questions on Google and SO and couldn't find anything directly related. There seem to be two similar (maybe?) questions in C#, but I don't know the language, so I didn't really understand the questions properly ([How to cast object to type described by Type class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206148/how-to-cast-object-to-type-described-by-type-class), and [Cast a variable to a type represented by another Type variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547594/cast-a-variable-to-a-type-represented-by-another-type-variable)).

I was experimenting with writing a generic scene-changing function in my **GameViewController** in SpriteKit. I made a **SceneChangeType** enum to use as a parameter. The error came in trying to optional cast a variable to what I expected to be a generic Type.

Just to clarify, I'm sure there are lots of reasons why this isn't a good idea. I can think of other ways to handle scene-changing, like just writing separate methods for each scene change. I'm just curious from a technical standpoint why I'm getting an error that I can't understand.

The relevant code is as follows:

In **GameViewController.swift**

```
func genericSceneChangeWithType(sceneChangeType: SceneChangeType) {
    let expectedType = sceneChangeType.oldSceneType
    guard let oldScene = self.currentScene as? expectedType else { return }
    ...
}

enum SceneChangeType {
    case TitleSceneToGameScene
    var oldSceneType: SKScene.Type {
        switch self {
        case .TitleSceneToGameScene:
            return TitleScene.self
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

For clarification, **TitleScene** is a custom subclass of **SKScene**, and *self*.currentScene has type **SKScene?**.

On the line,

```
guard let oldScene = self.currentScene as? expectedType else { return }
```

I get the error,

```
'expectedType' is not a type
```

Am I just massively misunderstanding things here? I thought you could use similar syntax to return a generic type from a function (e.g. [Swift: how to return class type from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29196463/swift-how-to-return-class-type-from-function)).
Is the issue because it's a property?
Is this not even possible, or is there some other way to check the type if the expected type is not known until runtime?

To emphasise again, I'm **not** asking about better ways to change scenes, and I'm not sure I have any examples where this is **absolutely** necessary. But understanding why this doesn't work might help me, or others, to understand the workings of the language better.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea, you're just confusing runtime vs. compile-time information. When you cast with `as`, you need to provide a type *at compile time*. This could be an explicit type like `String`, or it could be a generic parameter (as generics are a compile-time feature). You cannot, however, pass a variable containing a type like `expectedType`.

What you can do instead is check:

```
if self.currentScene.dynamicType == expectedType
```

However, as this doesn't cast `currentScene`, it won't allow you to call any methods that are specific to `expectedType`. It also won't work if `currentScene` is a *subclass* of `expectedType`, and you probably want it to. The problem is that you're passing around types at runtime, when you need to know types *at compile-time* in order to call methods or cast.

What you need, therefore, are Swift language features that seem helpful but *work at compile-time*, and I can think of two:

**Generics**, something like:

```
func genericSceneChange<OldType: SKScene, NewType: SKScene>() {
    ...
}
```

**Overloading**, something like:

```
func changeTo(scene: OneType) {
    //do something
}

func changeTo(scene: OtherType) {
    //do something else
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thats because when you set *expectedType* to **SceneChangeType**, it's actually an instance of MetaType. [A metatype type refers to the type of any type, including class types, structure types, enumeration types, and protocol types.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html) Hence why you are unable to cast to it and receive that error message.

By passing in a Generic type, you should be able to get the functionality you are looking for.

```
func genericSceneChangeWithType<T>(sceneChangeType: T) {
  guard let oldScene = self.currentScene as? T else { return }  
}
```

Comment: While generics are totally the way to go, this particular implementation uses his original `sceneChangeType` parameter name in a very strange way. Unfortunately, he's going to need to redesign the whole scene change system--`SceneChangeType` is inherently a runtime way of doing things.

Comment: I agree with you, I was just trying to help him better understand why he was receiving the error **is not a type**. Don't necessarily agree with my generic function, just wanted to show him how to integrate it with his current approach.